# mysql query with LIKE may use index, but only use some len characters?

Tags: mysql

I have an SQL statement

```
select * from tb_name where field like 'abc_def_ghj%';
```

which can be as fast as

```
select * from tb_name where field like 'abc_def_ghj_defg%;
```

(there may be lots of field value starting with abc_def_qhj;

from the 12th letter are quite different).

I want to know if is there a special length for the index field, for example, only field(0,10) for the First ten letters effects;

Comment: *is there a special length for the index field, for example, only field(0,10) for the First ten letters effects* You may specify column prefix length in the index expression. For example, `CREATE INDEX idx (field(10))` creates the index by first 10 chars of column values. And for `where field like 'abc_def_ghj_defg%;` server may use either table scan or index scan with additional table scan, depends on statistic.

Answer (score 1):

(I assume you have `INDEX(field)`?)

If only a small percentage of rows match this, then it is fast:

```
like 'abc_def_ghj_defg%
```

If a large percentage of rows match this, then it is slow:

```
like 'abc_def_ghj%'
```

The speed difference has very little to do with lengths, just with number of rows that match.

If the collation is `..._ci`, then upper and lower case match each other.

Be aware that underscore (`_`) is a wildcard.

When timing, be sure to run a query twice.  Caching could make a big difference.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there a limits on the length of index keys in MySQL.

From ["15.22 InnoDB Limits"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-limits.html) (assuming you use InnoDB as storage engine because it's the most popular these days):

> - The index key prefix length limit is 3072 bytes for `InnoDB` tables that use
>   [`DYNAMIC`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html#glos_dynamic_row_format)
>   or
>   [`COMPRESSED`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html#glos_compressed_row_format)
>   row format.
>
>   The index key prefix length limit is 767 bytes for `InnoDB` tables that use the
>   [`REDUNDANT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html#glos_redundant_row_format)
>   or
>   [`COMPACT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html#glos_compact_row_format)
>   row format. For example, you might hit this limit with a [column
>   prefix](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html#glos_column_prefix)
>   index of more than 191 characters on a `TEXT` or `VARCHAR` column,
>   assuming a `utf8mb4` character set and the maximum of 4 bytes for each
>   character.
>
>   Attempting to use an index key prefix length that exceeds the limit returns an error.
>
>   If you reduce the `InnoDB` [page size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html#glos_page_size)
>   to 8KB or 4KB by specifying the
>   [`innodb_page_size`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_page_size)
>   option when creating the MySQL instance, the maximum length of the
>   index key is lowered proportionally, based on the limit of 3072 bytes
>   for a 16KB page size. That is, the maximum index key length is 1536
>   bytes when the page size is 8KB, and 768 bytes when the page size is
>   4KB.
>
>   The limits that apply to index key prefixes also apply to full-column index keys.

Comment: the column type is varchar(200), but the actual value is just less than 50 characters, so what you answered may not the real result, because when i use the sql "select * from tb_name where field = 'abc_def_ghj'" is very fast, but "like 'abc_def_ghj%'" is 300 times slower;

Comment: That doesn't contradict that there are limits in place. a) Those are *maximums* not minimums, the index keys can be defined to be shorter and b) a range query may still be more work (it has to continue even after `'abc_def_ghj'` was found for all the other strings with that prefix)) than a point query (it can stop once `'abc_def_ghj'` was found).

Comment: another case is where I query with 'ABC_DEF_GHJ_%', it's also fast than querying with 'abc_def_ghj_%'; and the actural rows are similar, both million.